# How to connect a TextField from the storyboard to the class in Xcode6

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6

I'm trying to connect a Text Field from Main.Storyboard to my ViewController class, so I'm dragging from the dot of "New Referencing Outlet" to the View Controller that I already passed inside the above code

```
@IBOutlet weak var textField : UITextField!
```

then the only choice I get is "view". What am I doing wrong?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you may not have the view controller selected in your storyboard. Try this - click on the header at the top of your storyboard so that the view controller gets a light blue 'selected' border. Then drag onto the yellow dot with the white square inside.

Comment: I did what you advised and it worked, though I still don't get a prompt in the window that appears to connect it with my UITextField Outlet. It only gives me the choice of "delegate" in the outlets. Is there any problem with my code above or is there a bug in TextFields?

Comment: The one line of code I can see is fine so the problem must be somewhere else. Without seeing more of your project it's difficult to diagnose. Have you tried control-dragging from the Text Field in your storyboard view controller into your source code and creating the connection that way? You can either drag onto your existing line of code or delete the code and drag into an empty line and use the pop-up to create a new line of code.

Comment: This way, by dragging into an empty line and use the pop-up it works. Thank you very much